# Spring MVC @ResponseBody , JSON, JSP. Trying to Return List<Objects> from Controller to JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to retrieve List of JSON data objects from Spring MVC Controller class in order to display that inside JSP using Ajax.

I have written Spring MVC Controller class which return the List of JSON Objects.

I am not able to understand how will i display those list of objects inside JSP.

I am able to see JSON data in the browser when i hit /shop url.

The problem lies in JSP where i am not able to retrieve data.
here is index.jsp

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function load() {
     $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: "json",
              url:        "/SpringMVCWithJSON/shop", //url to get list of json data.
              success:    function(msg) {
              var m=msg;
              var json = m ,
              obj = JSON.parse(json);
              for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
              var name= obj[i].name;
          alert(name);
}
     });
    </script>
```

Please suggest me how to display list of JSON object from Spring MVC controller to JSP using AJAX.

Thanks in Advanced. Any Suggestions/corrections would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/shop", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public List<Object> myJsonReturningMethod{.....}
```

In your javascript remove the following line:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json)
```

Comment: Can you provide the return class?

Comment: public class Shop {

 String name;
 
 String staffName[];
 
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public String[] getStaffName() {
  return staffName;
 }
 public void setStaffName(String[] staffName) {
  this.staffName = staffName;
 }
 
 public Shop() {
 } 
 
}  i have return list of this Shop class.  I am not able to understand how do i iterate this json list of object inside javascript. How could i see this data simple in alert?? in loop.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
  sendAjax();
});
 
function sendAjax() {
$.ajax({ 
    url: "/SpringMVCWithJSON/shop", 
    type: 'GET', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) { 
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
       alert(obj[i].name);
      }
      }
    },
    error:function(data,status,er) { 
        alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
});
}
</script> How do i Iterate data inside it?

Comment: I get data in JSON format something like [{"name":"sample","staffName":["a1","V1"]},{"name":"sample","staffName":["a2","V2"]},{"name":"sample","staffName":["a3","V2"]}]

Comment: What is the behavior that you are observing? Try doing an alert of obj. Let me know what that shows.

Comment: I just want to print list of json data inside jsp using ajax. I am just not able to understand how do i get that data inside jsp using ajax and print it inside alert.

Comment: I was asking for debugging purposes. What happens when you alert the obj?

Comment: in log is just says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o . the line number it give is out of scope where the html tag ends. It does not give any alert messages when i am trying to put alert on object.

Comment: Check your javascript. There probably is an unexpected "o" somewhere.

Comment: I think the error is inside (success : function(data) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
     alert(obj[i].name);
    }
   }) Here i have used obj = JSON.parse(data);// I still do not understand where is 'data' come from? because there is no ref anywhere in javascript which return 'data' object? if its not data then what i should use inside function(???)

Comment: When you enter the url in the browser, the browser makes an http request and the responseText is handled by the browser (displayed in this case).

However, when you are using ajax, the response is handed over as a parameter to your javascript success method. Hence the JSON response of your controller method becomes the "data"

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the latest javascript there? It is difficult to read code in the comments.

Comment: Thats really nice explanation of the response. So i guess the problem must be there while obj = JSON.parse(data); it is not able to parse the data. Since its a list of objects.

Comment: No. That will not be a problem because list of objects are represented in JSON like this:

`[{"key":"value"}{"key":"value"}{"key":"value"}{"key":"value"}]`

Comment: The problem is solved. I was iterating data in wrong ways. I have changed is it in following ways :-  success: function(data) { 
     for(var i =0;i < data.length-1;i++)
     {
       var item = data[i];
       alert(item.name + item.staffName );
     }
    }                     Thanks you very much Arjun for your quick attention towards issue and helped. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script>
function load() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/SpringMVCWithJSON/shop",
    success: function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i].name);
      }
    },
    error: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

There seems to be a problem with the closing of flower brackets in your code.